# How to convert my string '310519' to date object?

Tags: javascript

I have strings with dates in format '310519' ( it's 05/31/2019 ). How to convert my strings to date object?  `new Date('310519')` not working.

Comment: That is not a supported date format you need to manually split that string, 2nd answer from this question helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regex to reformat the string, then use `new Date(s)`:

```js
var s = "310519";
s = s.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '$2/$1/$3');
console.log(new Date(s));
```

With `.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/, '$2/$1/$3')`, you reformat the groups of two digits, bascally, swap the first and second group and insert `/` separators. `\d{2}` matches any two digits, `(...)` creates capturing groups that are referenced to with the help of placeholders like `$1`, `$2`, `$3` from the replacement part.

Comment: Please provide explanation to your answer so that readers having similar problems can learn better

Answer (score 1):

The [moment library](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) can handle dates in whatever format you specify:

```js
const source = "310519";
const date = moment(source, "DDMMYY");
console.log(date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```